# Longest sequence of 1's in an array in C

Tags: arrays, count, sequence

I have an array like this:

```
0011011100011111001
```

I'd like to find the longest sequence of 1's in this array, keeping note of the length and position of the starting point, here the length would be 5 and the starting point is 12.

Any ideas for how to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? looks like a homework...

Comment: Does the array consist of zeroes and ones only, or does it contain integer numbers and you are searching in the concatenated binary representation of these integers?

Comment: How does this code relate to the question you have posted? For start, your function uses a two-dimensional array, the question is about a one-dimensional array.

Comment: because what I want to get done is with a two-dimensional array. I only asked about a one-dimensional array so I can apply whatever help I get to doing it with a two-dimensional array myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a starting position and length initially to zero, then go through the array elements one by one, keeping track of the transitions between `1` and `0` with a simple state machine.

The state table looks like this:

```
              +----------------------------------------+
              |               lastNum                  |
              +------------------+---------------------+
              |         0        |          1          |
+---------+---+------------------+---------------------+
|         | 0 | Just get next    | Check/update runLen |
|         |   |  character       |  against previous   |
| thisNum +---+------------------+---------------------+
|         | 1 | Store runPos  ,  | Increment runLen    |
|         |   |  set runLen to 0 |                     |
+---------+---+------------------+---------------------+
```

Since you're only interested in `1` sequences, the initial state has `lastNum` set to zero to ensure a `1` at the start correctly begins a run. We also set up the initial "largest run to date" to have a size and position of zero to ensure it gets overwritten by the first *real* run.

There's a special edge case to this method because we have to detect if the final number in the list is `1` - if so, it means there will have been no `1 -> 0` transition at the end of the list for checking the final run of `1` numbers.

Since we will have exited the loop without checking that final run, we do a final check *as if* we were transitioning from `1` to `0`.

The pseudo-code goes something like this. First, the initialisation of all variables:

```
# Store the current maximum run of '1' characters (none) and initial state.

var maxLen = 0, maxPos = 0, lastNum = 0

# runLen and runPos will be set in a 0->1 transition before we use them.

var rnLen, runPos
```

Then we can simply iterate over each number in the list and detect transitions as per the diagram above:

```
# Iterate over entire list, one by one.

for curPos = 0 to len(list) - 1:
    # 0 -> 0: do nothing.

    # 0 -> 1: store position, set run length to 1.

    if lastNum == 0 and list[curPos] == 1:
        runPos = curPos
        runLen = 1
    endif

    # 1 -> 1: increment the current run length.

    if lastNum == 1 and list[curPos] == 1:
        runLen = runLen + 1
    endif

    # 1 -> 0: check current run against greatest to date.

    if lastNum == 1 and list[curPos] == 0:
        if runLen > maxLen:
            maxPos = runPos
            maxLen = runLen
        endif
    endif

    # Save current number into lastNum for next iteration.

    lastNum = list[curPos]
endfor
```

Then, finally, handling of the afore-mentioned edge case:

```
# If we finished with a `1`, need to check final run.

if lastNum = 1:
    if runLen > maxLen:
        maxPos = runPos
        maxLen = runLen
    endif
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it looks like homework, but the way I would do it is to store the start and length of the current run of 1's and that of the longest run. Iterate through the array. Whenever you change from a 0 to a 1, update the current start position and set length to 1. When the length is longer than the longest, update the longest length and start point. This runs in O(n) in the length of the input. This doesn't cover edge cases such as an array with no 1's.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array, keeping a count of the maximum number of consecutive ones found so far, and a separate count of the current number of consecutive ones.

```
let max_consec = 0
let curr_consec = 0
let i = 0
while i < array.size:
    if array[i] is 1:
        curr_consec++
    else:
        max_consec = Max(max_consec, curr_consec)
        curr_consec = 0
    i++
```

With a bit of thought, you should be able to figure out for yourself how to track the starting position.